# Problem with open map that is not holomorphic

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

This is the problem:

> Let $0\in\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ connected, open neighborhood of the origin.
>   Let $f,g:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic functions such that
>   $f(0)\neq0\neq g(0).$ Let $h:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ to be
>   $h(z)=f(z)\overline{g(z)}z^a\overline{z}^b$ with $a\neq b,$ positive
>   integers. Take $U$ a neiberhood of the origin. show that $h(U)$ is a
>   neighborhood of the origin.

Clearly, the only thing I have to prove is that $h(U)$ is open. $h$ is not holomorphic but I've tried to mimic the proof for the open map theorem with no succes. I've tried to some arguments with isolated zeros of $f$ and $g$ but no luck.

Comment: Are $a,b$ positive integers?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: Try to show that the product of two open maps is open. I think this is true, however I could be wrong.

Comment: @SeanHaight $z,\bar z$ are open, but their product isn't. This explains the $a\ne b$ condition.

Comment: You need to assume $\Omega$ is connected.

Comment: Yes, @zhw, you are so right $\Omega$ needs to be connected.

Comment: Does neighborhood really mean "open neighborhood"? I would not expect that $h(U)$ is open for *any* open neighborhood of $0$ in $\Omega$, but only for sufficiently small $U$. In that iInterpretation $h(U)$ would be a neighborhood of $0$ for any neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in $\Omega$ and it would be irrelevant whether $\Omega$ is connected.

Comment: Yes, you are right! i just have to show that i can find a radius $r>0$ such that the $B(0,r)$ (ball centred at origin with radius $r$) is contained in $f(U).$

Comment: Perhaps it is useful to observe that  $u(z)= z^a \overline{z}^b$ maps $B(0,r)$ to $B(0,r^{a+b})$. Let us assume that $a > b$, the case $a < b$ is similar. We have $\lvert u(z) \rvert = \lvert z \rvert^{a+b}$ and $u(z) = \lvert z \rvert^{2b} z^{a-b}$. For $w = se^{it}$ let $w' = s^{1/(a+b)} e^{it/(a-b)}$. Then $u(w') = w$.

Comment: @PaulFrost So $u$ is open map. How is this helpful?

Comment: I don't know whether it helps, it was just an observation. If $f,g$ are constant, we are ready.